# cluster in mongodb and how does it picks up the cores

Tags: node.js, mongodb, sequelize.js

So I am new to cluster and mongodb and i came across this bunch of code.

```
#!/usr/bin/env node
var cluster = require('cluster');
var os = require('os');
var app = require('../main')
var models = require("../models");


if(cluster.isMaster){
  var mCoreCount = os.cpus().length;
  console.log("Cores : ", mCoreCount);

  for (var i = 0; i < mCoreCount; i++) {
    cluster.fork();
  }

  cluster.on('exit', function(){
    cluster.fork();
  });
}else{
    models.sequelize.sync().then(function(){
      app.listen(app.get('port'), function(){
        console.log('api is live.' + app.get('port'));
      });
    });
}
```

So when I console I get cores as 4, I tried reading but I could not understand anything , If someone could point me whats going on here It will be a great help.
I understood that the greater the number of cores the node instances will increase , but I guess right now its picking up from my system, what happens in **production** ?.

Comment: What confuses you about this code running in production? There is also an os, cpu, cores...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This script is trying to get the more efficient way to launch the *NodeJS* app by creating a [fork](https://nodejs.org/api/cluster.html) for each available core on the hardware server.
It picks up the number of core with `os.cpus().length`

In production, it will append the same process, and the number of fork will depend of the number of available core production server.

Are you really sure the database is *MongoDB* in both environement ? We can't really tell without seeing the whole app code.